# How to step through line by line when debugging JavaScript with Opera Dragonfly?

Tags: asp.net, opera, opera-dragonfly

I'm a long-time user of Opera as a browser for general usage and due to various annoyances with Firefox I decided to give [Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/) a look. The first thing that has jumped out at me is when debugging JavaScript I can't seem to just step through my script line by line.

I'm using ASP.NET and my script is just a button click event. When I place my breakpoint on the first line of the function and click the button the breakpoint is hit as expected. It's here that I am confused. Dragonfly's window has four buttons on the top left - Continue, Step Into, Step Over and Step Out. If I click Step Over or hit F10 I am expecting that the debugger will step through the JavaScript just like Firebug but instead it seems to immediately skip over the rest of the function altogether. The same thing happens if I click Continue or hit F8. If I click Step Into or hit F11 I start descending into the jQuery JavaScript which is obiously not what I want!

Am I just missing something fundamental here? I'm using Opera 11.52 if it helps.

Just to add more information on the environment I'm working in, Here is a screenshot of my button click event with a breakpoint set on line 14. Execution pauses as expected when I click the button in the browser.

[image]

Now, I would expect that some keypress exists to simply bring me to line #15. In Firebug and the IE Dev Tools that keypress is F10. In Dragonfly though F10 seems to just skip the rest of the JavaScript code. The same applies to Shift+F11. F11 by itself brings me to this part of jquery.js which, as mentioned before, is not where I want to be.

[image]

Comment: I've seen F10 misbehave at times :-/, if you have a link somewhere that shows this problem I'd like to check if it's fixed in the Opera 12 previews.

Comment: BTW the only workaround is to set a breakpoint below the function you want to step over, use F10, clear the breakpoint and continue normally.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "set a breakpoint below the function you want to step over"?

Comment: In the first screenshot above you'd set a new breakpoint on line 15, press F8, and clear the breakpoint on line 15 when stopped there. I keep trying to nail down the stepping bugs in Dragonfly because this is really very annoying..

Comment: Okay, that seems to work even if it is very fiddly. In the absence of anything more suitable if you want to put your comment in as an answer I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: Sure, I've elaborated a bit - plus spent some hours on trying to debug it. I've found at least two cases where this might happen, but if possible I would still like to see your code too because there may be even more bugs causing this problem.. :-/

Comment: Wow. I've just been trying to debug an opera-specific problem and came across this bug on my first try. It, well, pretty much makes the debugger useless. Which is really too bad, because it otherwise it looks like a very nice alternative to the Chrome debugger, with a really slick search tool. But .. really? If such a basic feature doesn't work, can anyone really be using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a bug in Opera which sometimes causes problems when stepping over or out of functions with the Dragonfly debugger.

The only workaround is to set a breakpoint below the function you want to step over, use F10, clear the breakpoint and continue normally. For example, in the first screenshot above you'd set a new breakpoint on line 15, press F8, and clear the breakpoint on line 15 when stopped there. I know this is really annoying :-(

I've done a bit more work on trying to reproduce this bug so that it can get fixed. In Opera's (closed) bug tracker this is now tracked as issue CORE-42532, it seems we're making some progress there so hopefully this annoyance will be gone some day. Meanwhile good luck with your debugging!

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [documentation for the javascript debugger](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/documentation/debugger/).

Comment: Yes, I've read that page but it's just adding to my frustration and confusion. What I'm trying to do surely isn't that unusual!